# loading resources in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop

normally, loading resources in the Scala REPL is done like this:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resource-file")
```

[see here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/12475.html)

but this doesn't find resources from jars I load using the usual startup

```
spark-shell --jars list-of-jars
```

How are resources loaded in spark-shell? (am I referencing the wrong ClassLoader?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the prefix "/". I tested in Spark shell and both `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resource-file")` and `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("resource-file")` worked. However, I would recommend using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` since it doesn't rely on what `getClass()` returns.